# Read a dat file consisting of two columns of floats separated by a comma into two arrays

Tags: java

I have a dat file that consisting of two floats per row separated by a comma like this:

```
1.224744871391589,0
1.224747983922952,2.77796297222263e-06
1.224757321499289,1.111185188889053e-05
1.224772884067338,2.500166675000371e-05
1.224794671538333,4.444740755556212e-05
1.224822683788003,6.944907430556598e-05
1.224856920656575,0.0001000066670000149
1.224897381948776,0.000136120185638909
1.224944067433837,0.0001777896302222487
```

I know the length of the columns beforehand (30000). I would like to store each column in a separate array and return it. I know how to do this in python (using line.split to get the two floats per row) but am not sure what is the most efficient way to do in Java (I care about speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a BufferedReader and 2 arrays (1 per column), reader will read the next double and store it in the respective array (you should alternate between arrays continuously).

This should do the job. I haven't tested it.

```
double[] firstColumn = new double[30000];
double[] secondColumn = new double[30000];
int index = 0;

try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.dat"));
      String str = in.readLine();

      while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] values = str.split(",");
             firstColumn[index] = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
             secondColumn[index++] = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);         
      }

       in.close();
    } 
catch (IOException e) 
{
  // do the logging.
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. But what about the comma. Should I simply keep reading it into a temporary char variable. Is that the simplest thing to do.